# I'm not able to validate my ipa from command line but it work from xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, validation, terminal

I'm trying to validate my app by command line using this :

xcrun altool --validate-app -f myapp.ipa -t ios -u "id" -p

But I'm getting this error :

altool[1043:29194] *** Error: Unable to validate archive 'myapp.ipa': (
    "Error Domain=ITunesSoftwareServiceErrorDomain Code=-21017 "Could not find the main bundle or the Info.plist is missing a CFBundleIdentifier in 'myapp.ipa'." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Could not find the main bundle or the Info.plist is missing a CFBundleIdentifier in 'myapp.ipa'., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unable to validate your application.}"
)

I exported an IPA from Xcode, directly in Xcode I can validate and upload it but I don't understand this error when I'm trying to do it from the command line

Comment: Hello, are you using any pods ? (Cocoapods) ?

Comment: Hello Lapinou, i'm using pods for facebook sdk : FBSDKLoginKit, FBSDKShareKit, Bolts